# Erro ao Conectar em MySQL PDO

Tags: mysql

Meu MAC desligou do nada e quando ligou de novo parou de funcionar o MySql.

O MySQL é instalado pelo MAMP.

Está dando este erro quando acesso **apenas um** site:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (61)

Nenhum site funciona. Fiz no **Laravel**.

Já dei permissão de pasta. Mas não consigo resolver por nada.

Só não reinstalei o MAMP ainda.

### Problema

Quando desligou o MAC eu estava colocando uma coluna em uma tabela. 
Agora fui ver a tabela não abre mais, dá erro. Não carrega os registros. Tem como recuperar ?

Já dei `CHECK TABLE SUBMENUS`, mas não repara. E também fiz `REPAIR TABLE SUBMENUS`, nada também.

Erro:

> Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Comment: Experimenta isto - `sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock`

Comment: Eu fiz isso. Por fim, acabei descobrindo o problema @Edilson. Quando o MAC desligou eu estava mexendo na Base de Dados, fazendo uma alteração. E isso corrompeu uma tabela. Eu debuguei no Laravel aonde estava parando... e obviamente estava parando em uma Middleware que montava o Menu do Sistema. Daí vi que o problema estava quando o código tentava acessar a tabela `Submenus`. Resumindo, eu perdi a tabela. Que bom que eram poucos dados e eu sabia de cabeça. Mas eu rodei esse código que você falou. Boa.

Comment: Ainda bem que localizaste o problema.